# How can I resolve child duplication error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

How to resolve child duplication error:

> Error: Duplicated named argument 'child'.
> child: CenteredView(

This is my code:

```
Container(
               child: RaisedButton(
                 onPressed: (){},
                  child: Text(
                   'Alcoholic Beverages',
                   style: TextStyle(
                     decoration:TextDecoration.underline,
                     fontSize: 25,
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
                 child: CenteredView(
                     child: Column(
                         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                         children: <Widget>[
                           NavigationBar()
                         ]
                     )
                 )
             ),
               ]
        ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Container` widget can only have one child.
To lay out multiple children, let this widget's child be a widget such as `Row`, `Column`, or `Stack`.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Container** you have two child, when **Container** widget can take only a single child. So you need to use some widget that can have more than one child. **Column** and **Row** allows you to do that.
Check this link to read more about multi-child widget, unlike Container, which is single-child widget, Column and Row are Multi-child widget.
[Multi-Child Widget](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout#Multi-child%20layout%20widgets)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';

class selClass extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: sel(),
    );
  }
}

class sel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _selState createState() => _selState();
}

class _selState extends State<sel> {
  String _date = "Not set";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child:SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(   child: Column ( 
children: [
               RaisedButton(
                 onPressed: (){},
                  child: Text(
                   'Alcoholic Beverages',
                   style: TextStyle(
                     decoration:TextDecoration.underline,
                     fontSize: 25,
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
                  CenteredView(
                     child: Column(
                         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                         children: <Widget>[
                           NavigationBar()
                         ]
                     ),
                 ),
               ]
        ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Container can have only One Child . That's why you're getting this error. You need to Column if your view is vertical or Row if your view is horizontal. Use this to solve your problem:

```
Column :

Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Alcoholic Beverages',
                style: TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  fontSize: 25,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            CenteredView(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[NavigationBar()])),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

OR

Row :

Container(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Alcoholic Beverages',
                style: TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  fontSize: 25,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            CenteredView(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[NavigationBar()])),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```